# Solidity contract runs on Ganache but gives runtime errors on Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ganache

I have a really simple contract. The tests run great on Ganache, but on Geth I get strange runtime errors.

Solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract SimpleStorage {
  mapping(address => uint256) public favoriteNumbers;

  function setFavorite(uint x) public {
    favoriteNumbers[msg.sender] = x;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage") 

contract('SimpleStorage', (accounts) => {
    const [bob, alice] = accounts
    it("should verify bob and alice's favorite numbers default to 0", async () => {
        const ssContract = await SimpleStorage.deployed()
        const bobNum = await ssContract.favoriteNumbers.call(bob)
        assert.equal(bobNum, 0,
            "bob's default value was non-zero")

        const aliceNum = await ssContract.favoriteNumbers.call(alice)
        assert.equal(aliceNum, 0,
            "alice's default value was non-zero")
    })
```

Everything is great in Ganache:

```
$ truffle test --network ganache  --reset --compile-all
Using network 'ganache'.

Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/SimpleStorage.sol...


  Contract: SimpleStorage
    ✓ should verify bob and alice's favorite numbers default to 0 (85ms)


  1 passing (168ms)
```

When I run the same contract on Geth I get:

```
$ truffle test --network devlocal  --reset --compile-all
Using network 'devlocal'.

Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/SimpleStorage.sol...


  Contract: SimpleStorage
    1) should verify bob and alice's favorite numbers default to 0
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (27ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: SimpleStorage
       should verify bob and alice's favorite numbers default to 0:
     Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
      at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:25:1)
      at SolidityFunction.validateArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/function.js:74:1)
      at SolidityFunction.toPayload (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/function.js:90:1)
      at SolidityFunction.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/function.js:131:1)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:135:1
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:126:1
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Interestingly, if I change the second call to `favouriteNumbers` on line 11 to `const aliceNum = await ssContract.favoriteNumbers.call(alice, 0)`, then the test passes in Geth (but fails in Ganache obviously).

Another observation:

```
ssContract.setFavorite(33, {from: bob})
const newBobNum = await ssContract.favoriteNumbers.call(bob)
```

Does what you would expect in Ganache by setting `newBobNum` to 33. In Geth, the value stays as 1.

My Geth command looks like this:
`geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30310 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi
 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://3fb9ff124dc8a51ef4b70bc1204efd0a4f3421965c396e027a9774aa0b9ee322e
c9215c5440f695a059b96a98c2ed175ffb114f586cd002700bc2857ebdd3d59@127.0.0.1:30304' --networkid 1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0xa94
2cf835a063c110ee5ebd80277ef6a87c7e7cc' --password node1/password.txt --mine`

I have tried setting up Geth using Docker as well as locally. Exact same error in both https://medium.com/@javahippie/building-a-local-ethereum-network-with-docker-and-geth-5b9326b85f37
https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

My genesis file with 2 accounts:

```
 {
  "config": {
    "chainId": 555,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "clique": {
      "period": 2,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5b97603b",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000370c66e48e5d3e4eef6c9f1cd8e060107a02c60aa942cf835a063c110ee5ebd80277ef6a87c7e7cc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {

    "370c66e48e5d3e4eef6c9f1cd8e060107a02c60a": {
      "balance": "0x2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "a942cf835a063c110ee5ebd80277ef6a87c7e7cc": {
      "balance": "0x2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? This *feels* like a Geth issue. But two guides can't both be wrong, so I'm probably missing something really basic.

Thank you for the help,
Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple logic:

In the 1st case - `[bob, alice] == [accounts[0], accounts[1]]`

In the 2nd case - `[bob, alice] == [accounts[0], undefined]` or `[undefined, undefined]`

Ganache allocates 10 accounts by default, unless you explicitly state otherwise, for example:

```
ganache-cli
--account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,99999999999
--account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002,99999999999
```

However, when you run Geth, you need to explicitly state how many accounts you want have.

So in your Geth `genesis.json` file, make sure that you allocate at least 2 accounts, for example:

```
"alloc": {
     "bf9fa87bc92581a1512c658557451965af5316a5": {"balance": "99999999999"},
     "0ab1cec1b01b5034b763956b920f9ce8b0afbcec": {"balance": "99999999999"}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have two accounts in my genesis file.

Comment: @Pavel: Make sure you unlock them (as Ganache does internally).

Comment: I think they are unlocked. I see this in Geth output early on:
INFO [09-17|14:42:23.387] Unlocked account address=0xa942Cf835a063c110eE5eBd80277EF6A87C7E7cc
INFO [09-17|14:42:23.387] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1
INFO [09-17|14:42:23.387] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0xa942Cf835a063c110eE5eBd80277EF6A87C7E7cc
INFO [09-17|14:42:23.387] Commit new mining work                   number=1 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=181.481µs

Comment: @Pavel: add `console.log(accounts)` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I was unlocking only 1 account per Geth instance. After creating a couple of more accounts and passing them to each instance of Geth, it no longer complains about this part.